# RUN pwd does not seem to work in my dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am studying on Docker these days and confused that why `RUN pwd` just does not seem to work while running my docker file.

I am working on IOS

and the full content of my docker file can be seen as below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER xxx

RUN mkdir -p /ln && echo hello world > /ln/wd6.txt

WORKDIR /ln

RUpwd

CMD ["more" ,"wd6.txt"]
```

as far as my understanding,
after building the docker image with the tag 'wd8'and running it, I supposed the result should show like this

```
~ % docker run wd8
::::::::::::::
wd6.txt
::::::::::::::
hello world

ln
```

however, the fact is without `ln`.

I have tried with `RUN $pwd`, and also added ENV at the beginning of my dockerfile, both do not work.

Please help point out where the problem is.

ps: so I should not expect to see the directory 'ln' on my disk, right? since it is supposed to be created within the container...?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKTH.png)

[1227](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZOfx.png)

Comment: You seem to be lacking the basics about docker containers and Dockerfiles; I suggest you review the Docker documentation

Comment: `RUN pwd` will print the working directory during **build time** not run time.

Comment: @DannyB I checked the logging info generated during the bulid time, I did not see the working directory was printed...could you please help to check the img i just uploaded?

Comment: @Paolo thx for your suggestion. i am new to docker and just studied on some examples from some tutorials..maybe the progress is a bit slow but is ongoing. :)

Comment: The output of each docker build step is collapsed when it is completed successfully. Run this to see your `pwd` output: `docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t temp .`

Comment: @DannyB thx a lot. I saw the output now after using this cmd. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple reasons you don't see the output of the `pwd` command, some of them already mentioned in the comments:

- the `RUN` statements in your `Dockerfile` are only executed during the build stage, i.e. using `docker build` and not with `docker run`
- when using the [BuildKit backend](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) (which is the case here) the output of successfully run commands is collapsed; to see them anyway use the `--progress=plain` flag
- running the same build multiple times will use the [build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) of the previous build and not execute the command again; you can disable this with the `--no-cache` flag

Comment: thx for your detailed answer. After adding the 2 flags, I saw the result shown during the build time, in ```#7``` on the attached pic '1227' at the end of my post.

Comment: second point helped